# find song with partial name in iTunes

Tags: applescript, itunes

I know how to play a song in a playlist by name, but lets say I want to make it so that white space and case don't matter when I'm playing that song.

So if I want to play "someSong", "some song" or "Some Song", I want to still play a song with name "Some song" in my playlist.

How do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
set yourSong to "yoursongname"
set yourPlaylist to "your playlist"

set searchString to {}
repeat with i from 1 to count of yourSong
    set aChar to text i of yourSong
    if aChar ≠ space then
        set end of searchString to aChar & " *?"
    end if
end repeat
set searchString to searchString as text

tell application "iTunes" to set plTracks to name of every track of playlist yourPlaylist
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to linefeed
set plTracks to plTracks as text
set AppleScript's text item delimiters to {""}
set targetSong to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of plTracks & " | grep -Ei " & quoted form of searchString

log targetSong
display dialog "Now Playing: " & targetSong buttons {"Cancel", "OK"} default button "OK" giving up after 2

tell application "iTunes" to play track targetSong of playlist yourPlaylist
```

Comment: hey- to check if this works, how do I println? I've tried log(var), but that doesn't seem to do anything

Comment: You can test it by running it in AppleScript Editor. Populate the yourSong variable with the name of a song with no spaces and in the wrong case. Populate the yourPlaylist variable with the name of the playlist which yourSong is in.

Comment: I have edited the script to log the value of targetSong and display it briefly before it plays.